# upload image - modal popup MVC doesn't close

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, serialization, modal-dialog

I have problem. I open my website on for example on: localhost:9999/Product/Index

When I click Create icon that displays a modal popup with page /Product/Crate

I click Save.

All the records in the database correctly, but it redirects me to page /Product/Crate, and I would like to only close my modal window.

What sholuld I do?

**Model:**

```
public partial class Prod
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public byte[] PFile { get; set; }
}
```

**Index View:**

> @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Products", FormMethod.Post, new {
>   enctype = "multipart/form-data" })){
>
> @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Create", "Products", null, new { data_modal = "", id = "btnCreate", @class = "btn btn-small
>   btn-primary pull-right fa fa-cart-plus" })
>
> @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Create", "Products", null, new { id =
>   "btnCreate", @class = "btn btn-small btn-primary pull-right fa
>   fa-cart-plus" })
>
> }

**Create View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Products", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductName, "Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductName)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductDescription, "Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProductDescription)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProductDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PFile, "File", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PFile, new { type = "file", name = "imageF" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PFile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Anuluj</button>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Zapisz" />
            </div>
        }
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "PFile")] Prod pro, HttpPostedFileBase imageF)
        {                    
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                    if (imageF != null)
                    {
                        pro.PFile= new byte[imageF.ContentLength];
                        imageF.InputStream.Read(pro.PFile, 0, imageF.ContentLength);
                    }


                     db.Prods.Add(pro);
                     db.SaveChanges();
                     return Json(new { success = true });

            }

            return PartialView("Create", pro);
        }
```

**modalform.js**

> $(function () {
>
> ```
> $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
>
> $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
>
>     // hide dropdown if any
>     $(e.target).closest('.btn-group').children('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
>
>
>     $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
>
>
>         $('#myModal').modal({
>             /*backdrop: 'static',*/
>             keyboard: true
>         }, 'show');
>
>         bindForm(this);
>     });
>
>     return false;
> });
> ```
>
> });
>
> function bindForm(dialog) {
>
> ```
> $('form1', dialog).submit(function () {
>     $.ajax({
>         url: this.action,
>         type: this.method,
>         data: $('#file').serialize(),
>         contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
>         success: function (result) {
>             if (result.success) {
>                 $('#myModal').modal('hide');
>                 //Refresh
>                 location.reload();
>             } else {
>                 $('#myModalContent').html(result);
>                 bindForm();
>             }
>         }
>     });
>     return false;
> }); }
> ```

Please help to solve this.

Comment: Well try to remove the line `location.reload();`, this should prevent the page from reloading

Comment: without change. Anyone have any ideas?